# Is it normal to have 500-900 MB of Other after restoring iPhone 4s?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I just had an **iPhone 4S (8G)** upgraded to **iOS 7.1.2**, and now, the capacity of my iPhone is **6.0GB**.

I **restored** my iPhone to **factory settings** via *Restore iPhone* in iTunes several times. I did not backup anything, and I always choose *Set up as a new iPhone*, and I did not connect any iTunes or iCloud account. But everytime there are several hundreds MBs of *Others* (between 500MB and 900MB, values differ everytime).

I also tried to reset all settings and data directly from my iPhone, but to no avail.

Is that normal to everyone or there's something wrong with my iPhone?

Comment: Did you mean that you've restored the iPhone to factory settings over the time with different numbers or that you actually did it several times in the same day with different results?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and editing. I did this several times in the **same** day with different results. I wonder what kind of data in _'Others'_. Can I delete them? I searched the web and some posts say that size of _'Others'_ grow over time, but can be deleted by _Restore to iPhone_ in iTunes.